# Visual Studio common 2019 asks for proxy settings

Tags: c#, visual-studio, internet-explorer, proxy

Last week I had to reinstall everything on my laptop. And so I needed to download Visual Studio again. Befor Reinstallation I had Visual Studio Express 2017 installed. Now I installed Visual Studio Community 2019.
I have a (surely!) running code. In this code I want to download an excel file from an internal sharepoint. This worked before without problems.
But when I tried to run the code again it got the following error message:

Exceptional error during a web client request. Error in creating the web proxy specified in the configuration section system.net/defaultProxy.

I tried out this already:
[How to set proxy in visual studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41936478/how-to-set-proxy-in-visual-studio-2015)
I tried to put this lines into app.config and also to into devenv.exe.confi in my installation directory:

```
<system.net>
<defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" enabled="true">
<proxy bypassonlocal="true"   proxyaddress=   "http://yourproxyaddress.net:8080" />
</defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

But it didn´t helped. Then I received this error message:

The underlying connection has been closed: The connection to the remote server cannot be established. An invalid argument was given.

The earlier code did not need any proxy, it was running before without any problem.
I invested already so much hours to try out different setting combinations.
Have anybody an idea? Please help me.

Best wishes
Begi

Comment: Its usually the startup page, and it usually picks up settings from internet explorer I round

Comment: @Bugfinder: So you mean that I only have to set the internet explorer right? Ok I w will try this out without this proxsettings.

Comment: Without settings in the app.config I receive the same errormessage. I put in the proxysettings in the internet explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:
I stored the code under a network drive to prevent loosing again code in future.
When I pasted the code back to my desktop, then it worked like before without any defaultProxy-settings.
Thank you very much for your answers.