# How to configure proxy in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, proxy, visual-studio-2019

I would like to download python packages via Visual studio. I would like to configure the proxy for downloading these packages.

> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None,
> redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
> 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection
> object at 0x000001E616804630>: Failed to establish a new connection:
> [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/pydotplus/

I tried the following steps, which were not successful:

1. Adding global proxy using `netsh`(https://superuser.com/a/375525/584920)
2. Modifying the `devnet.exe.config` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/41936608/2614539)

Note: I configured proxy for GitHub, which works like a charm inside Visual Studio.

Comment: how did you manage to get the proxy for github in VS? I have also tried the steps you did above with no luck..

Comment: @nat for that you have to set the username/password/domain values for Git. This is the solution I used: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68289431/7389293

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Visual Studio in a Microsoft Windows environment. Your proxy settings should be configured via Internet Explorer either in Control Panel via Visual Studio in the following manner...

- Open Visual Studio, then click on Tools-> Options...
- In the Environment section scroll to and click on Web Browser, then click on Internet Explorer Options...
- On your Internet Explorer Options click on the Connections tab, then click on the LAN Settings... button and place a check mark on the check box labeled "Use a proxy server for your LAN (These settings will not apply to dial-up or VPN connections)". Then click on the Advanced tab. This is where you will place your proxy server settings.

If you are using a Mac, and are either attempting to install Visual Studio or use it's services such as Azure, etc... You may want to take a look at the following link via [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-and-use-visual-studio-behind-a-firewall-or-proxy-server?view=vs-2019), which explains that endpoints need to be opened flor proxy/and firewall settings.

Comment: I use windows environment, The default proxy is already set for IE, which didn't work.

Comment: @Dineshkumar have it been solved?

Answer (score 5):

I do also struggled a lot for signing in & getting license updated. What I found is that  in environment option select system web browser instead of embedded browser solved my problem.

[image]

I could log in external browser & was able to sign in eventually update the license.

Answer (score 5):

Tools->Options->Web Browser->Internet Explorer Options->Connections-> LAN settings-> Proxy server -> Advance
add your proxy IP and port here.

Comment: What if I want to save proxy user and password?